# Should I replace Magento with Drupal for my e-commerce solution?

Tags: commerce

I am working on an e-commerce project. Essentially, it's a 'expansive product catalog -> shop cart; users database' type of thing. Everything is still in development environment. I am trying out Magento, I have mixed feelings about it. It is plug-n-play powerful, it seems to suit a lot of situations out of the box. However, now that I am getting to know it better, I see that I will have to get my hands dirty and code, customize, add features of my own, concerning website visual and non-visual design.

Is Drupal easier to work with for a developer/designer? How can product catalog importing/exporting be handled in Drupal? With Magento, I use Magmi and csv, which I love. I will definitely be implementing some kind of automated catalog updating, which I was planning to do with Magmi; that is very important to me.

In general, could you advise on your experiences on Drupal v. Magento for e-commerce?

### Edit:

## Conclusion:

I will be switching to Drupal, because I have found that even though Magento has many mature built in features, I only need a select few of them, and I have too little control over them, it feels like it is cluttered and rigid in my situation. I need something that is more friendly to 'going under the hood', and I think Drupal is it. I think if I was a better programmer, I could get Magento to suit my needs, but I'm afraid I'm not. Goodbye, Magento.

Comment: Drupal is easier to work with than Magento in general but on the e-commerce side of things Magento is far more powerful and mature than Drupal commerce. You have to think Drupal commerce is just some module that works with the framework where as Magento is all about e-commerce.

Comment: Before you spend too much time, give [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) a try. I explained the reasons [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40346/required-modules-to-develop-a-ecommerce-website/40358#40358). Try both and be aware of the pros/cons before you make a decision on the ecommerce module. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I plan to use Drupal Commerce. I feel that it's more future proof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having never used Magento, I'd say go with Drupal + Drupal Commerce ;-)

Check out the following articles though:

- [Magento vs Drupal Commerce](http://www.richardcarterconsultancy.com/2012/07/magento-vs-drupal-commerce/)
- [E-Commerce: Which CMS is better for e-commerce? Magento vs. Drupal? Others? (Quora)](http://www.quora.com/E-Commerce/Which-CMS-is-better-for-e-commerce-Magento-vs-Drupal-Others)
- [Drupal Vs. Magento (eHow)](http://www.ehow.com/info_12184137_drupal-vs-magento.html)
- [Magento vs Drupal Commerce (drupal.org)](http://drupal.org/node/710466)
- [Google ;-)](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=drupal%20commerce%20vs%20magento)

Drupal will allow you to import products with a combination of [Feeds](http://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) and [Commerce Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_feeds) or [Commerce Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_migrate) (the latter requiring a bit more work).

I think at the end of the day it comes down to your personal needs.  If you don't need a fully functional CMS (or CMF...[make your own mind up](http://palantir.net/blog/drupal-not-cms)), then better the devil you know; might as well go with Magento.

If you want a whole integrated solution, then Drupal is clearly the winner.  I'm pretty sure there are a couple of dev houses around where I am who are migrating sites from Magento to Drupal Commerce, but I've not heard of anyone doing it the other way around.

Lastly, depending on the complexity of your project you may have to get your hands dirty with Drupal too, but it's not that hard :).

Comment: Thanks! Feeds and Migrate is exactly what I'll need. I came to a conclusion that Magento is too rigid for me and Drupal is too 'lego' not to use it. I guess my personal preference is a CMS (or rather CMF) that is designed to be shaped. I love everything I'm hearing about it. And the large community and presence of support as opposed to Magento's Community dist is attractive as well.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with Magento I can tell you that theming it is very difficult compare to theming in Drupal. If you're using a custom theme for your site and not one of those premade themes then you're gonna have a hard time figuring out how to theme you Magento store. The support is also scarce if you're not subscribed to the very pricy enterprise version of Magento. Magento have lots of cool features out of the box but nothing you can't find in contributed modules for Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

My two pennies!

If you want to just do eCommerce and can handle the headaches of troubleshooting in the dark a little, then go for Magento. It is rock solid and works pretty much out-of-the-box.

That said, it is a bit tricky to theme and customising it to your will is quite hard.

Drupal is much more friendly if you are a low-middle weight coder because the contributed modules all have so many options to fiddle with in the backend without ever getting your hands dirty with too much code.

I would suggest that you allocate three days to each platform and see how far you are able to get with each one and which you prefer. The three days that you loose on the 'wrong' platform will be made up for with the time that you save using your preferred solution.

Both are cool, both are different.

Comment: Good insight! I've been toying with Magento for weeks now, it seemed very powerful at first, but, as you point out, I soon felt overwhelmed by its under-the-hood complexity and lost hope to effectively customize it.

Comment: I'm currently working on two projects, one Drupal, one Magento. I have reached a barrier on both. However, I always tend to feel that with Drupal, "I will work this out in time", whereas with Magento I often feel, "Oh goodness, this could be a major headache!"

Comment: I get the same impression with Magento.